# Obtener dos datos de una consulta (Angular)

Tags: nodejs, typescript, api, angularjs, express

Soy nuevo en el desarrollo web y después de muchos días de investigar, revisar e intentar todo lo que he encontrado y lo que conozco no he logrado solucionar este problema.
Estoy desarrollando una aplicacion web en angular con Node JS que esta enlazada a una REST API con mysql y express.
Mi problema se basa principalmente cuando intento obtener los datos de Correo y NoEmpleado los cuales se obtienen desde el login para poder mandarlo a una ventana de reportes pero cuando intento obtenerlo solo me muestra:

```
 login: [{"NoEmpleado":111,"Correo":"prueba","Contrasena":"pru","NoExtencion":112}]
```

o

```
login: [object Object]
```

lo que he intentado y he visto que me funciona es almacenarlo en localStorage pero unicamente me ha funcionado con un solo valor y no he sabido como obtener los dos datos que necesito y por el momento esto es lo único que he podido lograr por favor ayúdenme.

este es el lado de la API

**API.js**

```
router.post("/login", (req, res)=> {
 mysqlConnection.query(
  'select * from tb_login where NoEmpleado  = '+
          req.body.NoEmpleado+
          ' and Correo = "'+
          req.body.Correo+
          '" and Contrasena = "'+
          req.body.Contrasena,
  (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(data);
  }
);
});
```

Aqui se enlaza con la API y el back

**Serv.service.ts**

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    // obtencion de valores guardados del login

    this.NoEmpleadoSubject = new BehaviorSubject(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('NoEmpleado')!));
    this.NoEmpleado = this.NoEmpleadoSubject.asObservable();
    
    this.CorreoSubject= new BehaviorSubject(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Correo')!));
    this.Correo = this.CorreoSubject.asObservable();

  }
  // Obtencion de valores
  public get NoEmpleadoValue() {
    return this.NoEmpleadoSubject.value;
  }
public get CorreoValue(){
  return this.CorreoSubject.value;
}

login(login: Login | any) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.API_URI}/login`, login)
    .pipe(map
      (NoEmpleado => {
        localStorage.setItem('NoEmpleado', JSON.stringify(NoEmpleado));
        this.NoEmpleadoSubject.next(NoEmpleado);
        return NoEmpleado;
      })
      ,
      (Correo => {
        localStorage.setItem('Correo', JSON.stringify(Correo));
        this.CorreoSubject.next(Correo);
        return Correo;
      })
      );
  }
```

Este es el back de mi login y en donde creo yo que se encuentra el problema

**Login.conponent.ts**

```
inicio: Login = {
    Correo: "",
    NoEmpleado: "",
  };

login() {
    console.log(this.inicio);
     this.service.login(this.inicio).subscribe(
        (res) => { 
          let isEmpty = Object.entries(res).length === 0;
          if (res === null || isEmpty === true) {
            alert("Favor de llenar todos los campos correctamente");
            return;
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(["/reporte"]);
          }
        },
        (err) => console.error(err)
      );
```

Cuando se obtengan los datos se deberan de mandar aqui

**Reporte.component.ts**

```
 reportedn: Reporte = {
    NoEmpleado: this.service.NoEmpleadoValue,
    Correo: this.service.CorreoValue,
  };

  reporte() {
    // console.log(this.reportedn)
      this.service.reporte(this.reportedn).subscribe(
          (res)=>{
            if(this.reportedn !=null ||this.reportedn>0){
                this.router.navigate(['/agradecimiento']);
          }
        },
          err => console.error(err)
        )
      }
```

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.